Why can Yang-Mills mass gap fully explain confinement?
Having a gap in the spectrum doesn't exclude massive free quarks. It only tells us that there can't be free gluons or other massless excitations in QCD. I saw this statement in the opening paragraph of this paper arXiv:1502.04135. I'm not sure whether we have a rigorous argument for this statement.

Hi, welcome to Physics SE. It may be worth linking to the paper (which I notice is a short version of this) and quoting "the opening paragraph" (is that the abstract or the first post-abstract paragraph?) But do you want answers to your question to focus on your title or the paper? The undecidability of specific theories might not have the physical focus you're looking for. Also, special cases of physical interest might be decidable.

You are right, that mathematically proving the existence of a mass gap in Yang-Mills theory (one of the Millennium prize problems) would not directly imply confinement in QCD.
In their writeup of the problem, Jaffe and Witten identify three properties QCD must have which require an understanding of non-perturbative quantum field theory:

The mass gap
Quark confinement
Chiral symmetry breaking

Understanding quantum field theory without perturbation theory is an enormous theoretical challenge even at a physics level of rigor. Developing a fully mathematically rigorous framework is an enormous problem.
The Millennium prize problem therefore just focuses on the first of the three issues above, which can be formulated in pure Yang-Mills theory (as opposed to QCD which has quarks). This is a simplification of the physical case we ultimately care about, but already understanding this situation would require huge advances in our understanding of quantum field theory. Hopefully, this leap in understanding of Issue #1 in Yang Mills, would also help to shed light on how to tackle all the issues in QCD.
As stated in the problem statement I linked above:

There are many natural extensions of the Millennium problem. Among other
things, one would like to prove the existence of an isolated one-particle state (an
upper gap, in addition to the mass gap), to prove confinement, to
prove existence of
other four-dimensional gauge theories (incorporating additional fields that preserve
asymptotic freedom), to understand dynamical questions (such as the possible mass
gap, confinement, and chiral symmetry breaking) in these more general theories,
and to extend the existence theorems from R
4
to an arbitrary 4-manifold.
But a solution of the existence and mass gap problem as stated above would be
a turning point in the mathematical understanding of quantum field theory, with
a chance of opening new horizons for its applications.

Somewhat flippantly, your complaint might be phrased as "the mass gap in Yang Mills isn't nearly strong enough to prove confinement in QCD, why not focus on the more interesting problem," whereas the current situation is more like "confinement in QCD is so hard that we don't even have any idea how to do the easier problem of the mass gap in Yang Mills, so we should start there."
